# decoding scalacheck and scalatest code

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I was trying to decipher what this actually means

```
check { (n: Int) =>
  n > 1 ==> n / 2 > 0
}
```

from http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/writing_scalacheck_style_properties

I am first trying to decipher whether that body is

```
((n: Int) => n > 1) ==> n/2 > 0

or

(n: Int) => (n > 1 ==> n/2 > 0)
```

Which one would it be?  I am guessing the latter since check method takes a function though the method '==>' could be returning a function as well?

Next, I look at the check method signature at https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/12336175/

```
def check[A1,P](f: A1 => P)
  (implicit
     p: P => Prop,
     a1: Arbitrary[A1], s1: Shrink[A1]
  ) {
    check(Prop.property(f)(p, a1, s1))
}
```

I believe A1 would be the Int unless ==> returns a function and changes the return type(doubtful though I think).  I am not sure how to find the implicit function P => Prop in the scalacheck library.

I do notice there is an ExtendedBoolean that has a function ==> https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Prop.scala

Perhaps (n > 1) was converted to an ExtendedBoolean assuming the function was (n: Int) => (n > 1 ==> n/2 > 0) and then we get

```
ExtendedBoolean( n > 1 ).==>( n / 2 > 0 ) is called then.
```

Since the implementation of ==> for ExtendedBoolean is Prop(b) ==> p, I end up with

```
Prop( n > 1 ) ==> (n / 2 > 0)
```

I get really confused here as in call by name, the values are usually captured except there is no value for n at this point since it was originally a function.  ignoring my confusion for a second, the implementation of ==> for Prop is thus

```
def ==>(p: => Prop): Prop = flatMap { r1 =>
  if(r1.proved) p map { r2 => mergeRes(r1,r2,r2.status) }
  else if(!r1.success) Prop(r1.copy(status = Undecided))
  else p map { r2 => provedToTrue(mergeRes(r1,r2,r2.status)) }
}
```

so, we are calling this like so I think with another implicit version to Prop here

```
Prop( n > 1 ) ==> Prop(n / 2 > 0)
```

ok, and flatmap is

```
Prop(prms => f(this(prms))(prms))
```

hmmm, there must have been another conversion to Prop .  I start to trace prms and then look at the object Prop apply method for Booleans which is

```
def apply(b: Boolean): Prop = if(b) proved else falsified
```

but I can't resolve b to true or false since those functions have not been evaluated yet.  How is all this working together?  I think I am missing a few concepts here just barely.  Can someone explain this a bit better?

Comment: You are not missing anything. ExtendedBoolean evaluates the by name parameter [def ==>(p: => Prop) = Prop(b) ==> p](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Prop.scala#L318). "By name argument is not evaluated at the point of function application, but instead is evaluated at each use within the function. That is, the argument is evaluated using call-by-name."

Comment: I am used to stuff like log4scala where log.debug(=>String) takes something like log.debug("hi there "+name) and name IS defined already.  In this case, the by name is receiving something where name is not yet defined.  Is that even possible?  in the log.debug case, it captures the value of name in the closure in case the closure will be evaluated later(and it may not be of course), but I don't get it in the context of this code above.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is really a ScalaCheck question, but one way to avoid the whole question is to use ScalaTest's PropertyChecks syntax instead of ScalaCheck's (which is supported in ScalaTest by Checkers):

```
import org.scalatest.prop.Checkers._

check { (n: Int) =>
  n > 1 ==> n / 2 > 0
}
```

becomes:

```
import org.scalatest.MustMatchers._
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks._

forAll { (n: Int) =>
  whenever (n > 1) {
    n / 2 must be > 0
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am not trying to avoid the question.  I am trying to increase my knowledge of scala.  I am used to stuff like the log.debug( => String) where I can pass in "my name is "+name and name is captured as "dean" or something.  In the above scalacheck example, n does not have a value yet.  Can you really split a function into a closure that may get evaluated later like that?  or am I misreading the code maybe.